# Directive for validation the input value

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I created the directive for validating the input value. I need that on input some characters my input/form become ivalid. 
Here is my code, but it is not working.

```js
import {Directive, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS, ValidationErrors} from '@angular/forms';

const regExp = new RegExp('(>|<)+');

@Directive({
    selector: '[validator]',
    providers: [{
        provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
        useExisting: ValidatorDirective,
        multi: true
    }]
})

export class ValidatorDirective {
    @Input('validator') input;

    constructor() {

    }

    validate (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors {
        const value = control.value;
        const isValid = regExp.test(value);

        return isValid ? null : {
            validator: {
                valid: false
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.
Have a nice day.

Comment: What is not working? What do you expect to happen? What actually happens? How do you use this class you've created? Please create an online demo on StackBlitz or Plunker.

Comment: why are you using a input just use `[validator][ngModel]` get the value from `AbstractControl`

Comment: It should validate the input and when the input is { or } the form should throw an error on trying to save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `[validator][ngModel]` will do the trick in your case as you don't need to have an input for this directive

Like this

```
import {AbstractControl, ValidatorFn, Validator, FormControl, NG_VALIDATORS} from "@angular/forms";
import {Directive} from '@angular/core';


const regExp = new RegExp('(>|<)+');
function validateregex(): ValidatorFn {
  return (c : AbstractControl) => {

    const isValid = regExp.test(c.value);
    console.log("Valid"+isValid);
    //let isValid = c.value === 'Rahul';
    if(isValid){
      return null;
    }else{
      return {
        validator: {
          valid: false
        }
      };
    }

  }
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[regex][ngModel]',
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: ValidatorDirective, multi: true
  }]
})

export class ValidatorDirective implements Validator{

  validator: ValidatorFn;

  constructor() {
    this.validator = validateregex();
  }

  validate(c: FormControl) {
    return this.validator(c);
  }

}
```

Add this directive to `declarations` array of `Ngmodule`     `ValidatorDirective,`

The working example of the same [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/template).

Comment: Thank you for response. But it is not working as well.
In the Angular 1.5 I used `ctrl.$setValidity` and `ctrl.$parsers` for it. 
But here I don't know how to configure this functionality

Comment: @SashaSemanyuk I have updated the answer with the changes and it works for me i tested the same .

Comment: it return me the object of the directive with `valid: false`.
But i still can submit the form.
What can it be?

Comment: once you get hold of that you can now validate the errors , if some thing is returned its error else not . THis proves it works if it returns you values

Comment: I suppose that the form validates the error automatically on getting this result.
Am i wrong?

Comment: @SashaSemanyuk you need to display the correct error message it wont come automatically ?

Comment: No, as simply say, the input should have error border and the save button cannot be pressed.

Comment: @SashaSemanyuk you need to have disabled attribute for form . welcome